# Can't modify replica set priority

Tags: mongodb

I tried to modify priority of secondary MongoDB server. And priority changes only on two first servers.

```
rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 7,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "php01-dc.partkom.local:27017",
                    "priority" : 10
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "php02-dc.partkom.local:27017",
                    "priority" : 10
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "mysql02-dc.partkom.local:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "host" : "mysql01-dc.partkom.local:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 4,
                    "host" : "mysql-develop01.partkom.local:27017"
            }
    ]
}
```

Then I try:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority = 10
cfg.members[1].priority = 10
cfg.members[2].priority = 1
cfg.members[3].priority = 1
cfg.members[4].priority = 1
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

And priority member with _id 4 doesn't change :(

Where am I mistake?

Comment: Try **not** nominating the arbiter members when you make the changes and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Same result :( Any other idea?

Comment: Are you actually trying to set it to 1? That is the default priority hence no change. You were also trying to set arbiters which you cannot do.